# Install Logstash error JAVA (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I have followed the official documentation and written the following:

```
# Update repository
sudo apt-get update

# Install necessary things. Like SSL support and JDK
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https default-jdk -y

# Download and install the GPG KEY. Add the repository for elasticsearch version 7. Update and install logstash
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install logstash -y

# configure ES daemon
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable logstash.service
sudo systemctl start logstash.service
```

But the following appears:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/pleaserun-0.0.31/lib/pleaserun/platform/base.rb:112: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Successfully created system startup script for Logstash
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/logstash.service → /etc/systemd/system/logstash.service.
```

Although it is installed when I run the following command to test it manually:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }"
```

And the error repeats and does not allow to do anything.

```
luis@ubuntu18:~$ /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }"
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.11.1.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[FATAL] 2020-07-18 21:49:19.544 [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory. It is not writable.>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:528:in `validate'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:288:in `validate_value'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:199:in `block in validate_all'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1415:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:198:in `validate_all'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:310:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:268:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:88:in `<main>'"]}
[ERROR] 2020-07-18 21:49:19.633 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

I don't know if it's because of the java version (openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14) or another error. I have never used java so these errors confuse me a bit. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at error stack trace specific below line, **it means that `/usr/share/logstash/data` is not writable for the user who is running the logstash process.**

> error=>#<ArgumentError:
> Path"/usr/share/logstash/data"mustbeawritabledirectory.Itisnotwritable.>,

This is not a java issue, its a permission issue and you need to give write access to the user on this folder who is running this process and there are tons of resources on how to do it.